# The property of series $f(a)=\sum_{k} c_k a^{ib_k}$ ,$a\in \mathbb{R},a > 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given $f(a)=\sum_{k} c_k a^{ib_k}$ , a function of $a\in \mathbb{R},a > 0$ when $b_k\in \mathbb{R}, c_k\in \mathbb{C}$  is given as the parameter.

Claim: If $f(a)=0$ when $0<a<a_0$ for some given $a_0>0$, then $f(a)=0, a>0$.

Is the claim above right? For the analytic function it is satisfied. But $f(a)$ is not necessary an analytic function. I read the proof for the analytic function, but since it uses the fact that analytic function can be expressed as tayler expansion, the proof doesn't work there. So I am struggling about that. If it also satiesfies, do you know how to prove that? Thank you for advance!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it is an infinite series. Can you tell me how to prove that?@geetha290krm